# При изменении textview падает приложение

Tags: android-viewpager, android, java

Создал View Pager с 2-мя layout-ами c помощью фрагмента. В layout-ах разные элементы с разными id, пытаюсь изменить текст textview, но происходит вылет приложения, ошибок не выдаёт в компиляторе. Помогите, что делать?

Comment: Я прозрел. Я применил одно и тоже к двум разным layout-ам.

Comment: @levonchic, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автор сам нашёл проблему и почти год уже не возвращается, ответ не публикует. А нам не ответить, т.к. конкретики нет. Закрыть надо во имя метрик.